# How to display all posts assigned to some tag?

Tags: posts, tags

I have tag url - `example.com/tag/new-shoes` and I have 2 posts tagged with those keywords **new-shoes**.

I would like to display on this url `example.com/tag/new-shoes` all posts (titles and first keywords from posts)  tagged with **new-shoes**.

I have a problem, because url `example.com/tag/new-shoes` shows me exactly the same page like main page of my website.

I can not see titles of posts assigned to this tag.

I will be grateful for help.
Best,
Peter

Comment: Are you sure? wordpress would have to do what you say by default. You could provide real url to verify?

Comment: does your theme have a tag.php?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend giving the [wordpress tag template page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Tag_Templates) a read but the basic idea of what you want to do is something like this:

Create a `tag.php` fileand place it in your template.  This file will act like any other wordpress template and allow you to use "[The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)" which will allow you to cycle through each post that matches the url and display the info however you'd like.

```
<?php 
    if ( have_posts() ){
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_title();  //Displays the post title
            the_excerpt(); //Displays the post excerpt
        } 
    } 
?>
```

That block, inside `tag.php` will do what you are basically looking for in an extremely basic way.  Add HTML wrappers and/or call different functions to achieve the look you are going for.